# Rails Tutorial Sample_App fails on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, railstutorial.org

I reading Rails Tutorial and created a Sample_App.

My code is available here: https://github.com/namic/sample_app

Heroku is running the app here: http://afternoon-mist-7865.herokuapp.com/

It works in test, development and production environment on my laptop, but Heroku denies me the joy with "We're sorry, but something went wrong."

Any suggestions?

Solution:
Add to Gemfile:
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

And remember to run bundle install without production, if you dont want postgresql local:
bundle install --without production

Comment: Try to check the Heroku logs using the command     heroku logs

Comment: Did you remember to rake the heroku database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the logs and make sure you ran the migrations on heroku.

heroku run rake db:migrate

Comment: I dont have any models yet. Is it still necessary?

Comment: If you have a database configured in your database.yml...yes it will create the database itself.

Comment: database.yml says "sqlite3" for production. I believe Heroku wants me to use postgresql, rigth? Is it possible to avoid postgresql on my local setup, and still use it at Heroku?

Comment: add gem "pg" to your GemFile.rb